# deleting data in a dataset

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently taking the online standford class on databases, If you could help me solve this sql problem I would greatly appreciate it. Sorry I'm a complete noob.

```
Table Movie:
mID | title | year | director

Table Rating
rID | mID | stars | ratingDate

Table Reviewer
rID | name
```

Remove all ratings where the movie's year is before 1970 or after 2000, and the rating is fewer than 4 stars.

Comment: How is getting an answer here supposed to help you learn? At least show how you've tried to apply what you've learned so far to this problem.

Comment: Kindly add what homework/research you've done so far. This seems quite easy task, and putting the answer straight away isn't recommended.

Comment: I'd read about the DELETE statement, and also about the WHERE clause.

Answer (score 0):

That course was really good!  Didn't it come with its own forums?  I bet the question was already asked there.

Anyway, the first step is to find the rows you'd like to delete:

```
select  r.rID
from    Rating r
join    Movie m
on      r.mID = m.mID
where   (m.Year < 1970 or m.Year > 2000)
        and r.stars < 4
```

Now you can write a `delete` statement:

```
delete  from Rating
where   rID in
        (
        ... query from above ...
        )
```

Have fun with the rest of the course!

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your question is that you want to delete date from one table based on information in other tables. In order to achieve this, you could use sub select to identify the records to delete in table "Rating".

That sub select statement defines the relationship between Rating and Movie records plus it specifies the predicates on the movies year.

```sql
DELETE FROM Rating
 WHERE stars < 4 
   AND rID in 
       (SELECT r.rID 
          FROM Rating r, Movie m 
         WHERE r.mID=m.mID AND (m.year<1970 OR m.year>2000))
```